# Storing values in a hash

Tags: perl, parsing, reference, procedural-programming

Currently using perl to parse a config file consisting of multiple Sections, which in turn (can) consist of multiple definitions. My actual file has a completely different topic, but my parser would parse this example, too:

```
SECTION Foo
HP 200
ATT 50 Slap
ATT 100 Kick
DESC This is Foo. What is love?

SECTION Bar
HP 2
ATT 1 Mumble
DESC This is Bar. Baby don't hurt me!
```

Now, my parser uses mainly three variables to store data:

```
my %sections;
my $parsedName;
my %parsedVars;
```

While reading `SECTION Bar`, it has filled them as follows:

```
%sections = (); # empty
$parsedName = "Foo";
%parsedVars = (
  "HP" => "200",
  "ATT" => ("50 Slap","100 Kick"),
  "DESC" => "This is Foo. What is love?",
);
```

I think you get the point. Now, the content of the `%parsedVars` field is validated and if successful, the whole thing is stored to `%sections`, this is the code I use there:

```
use Storable qw(dclone);
# (...)
# Clone the Variables
$sections{$parsedName} = dclone (\%parsedVars);
# Prepare for next section
$parsedName = getSectionName $currentLine;
undef %parsedVars;
```

*And this is the part that hurts*, because I don't really want to deep-copy the whole `%parsedVars` and also I'm not allowed to include anything but `strict` due to a heavily restrictive runtime-environment.

I feel like I should detach the hash from its name and attach it to `$sections{$parsedName}`, but I can't wrap my head around how to get that done.

```
# These hiccups aside,
# my parser works fine, which is nice.
# One completeness wide:
# Result looks like this, no surprise!

%sections = (
  "Foo" => (
    "HP" => "200",
    "ATT" => ("50 Slap","100 Kick"),
    "DESC" => "This is Foo. What is love?",
  ),
  "Bar" => (
    "HP" => "2",
    "ATT" => "1 Mumble",
    "DESC" => "This is Bar. Baby don't hurt me!",
  ),
);
```

Answer (score 1):

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my %data;
my $section;

while (<DATA>) {
    chomp;
    next if /^\s*$/;

    my ( $key, $val ) = split ' ', $_, 2;

    if ( $key eq 'SECTION' ) {
        $section = $val;
    } else {
        push @{ $data{$section}{$key} }, $val;
    }
}

# Collapse single element arrays:
for ( values %data ) {
    for ( values %$_ ) {
        $_ = $_->[0] if @$_ == 1;
    }
}

use Data::Dump;
dd \%data;

__DATA__
SECTION Foo
HP 200
ATT 50 Slap
ATT 100 Kick
DESC This is Foo. What is love?

SECTION Bar
HP 2
ATT 1 Mumble
DESC This is Bar. Baby don't hurt me!
```

Outputs:

```
{
  Bar => { ATT => "1 Mumble", DESC => "This is Bar. Baby don't hurt me!", HP => 2 },
  Foo => {
           ATT => ["50 Slap", "100 Kick"],
           DESC => "This is Foo. What is love?",
           HP => 200,
         },
}
```

Answer (score 0):

One way would be to declare parsedVars as a scalar containing a hash reference instead of a hash.

When you begin parsing each section:

```
$parsedVars = {}; # Allocate a new hash

# store variables in the hash as you would before, but don't forget
# to dereference the hash ref!

# when finished parsing the section:
$sections{$parsedName} = $parsedVars;
```

Another way is to declare %parsedVars locally inside a scope which is entered for each section in the input file. That way each time you enter the scope you will get a fresh hash:

```
while (<FILE>) {
    if (/^SECTION: (\w)+/) {
        $parsedName=$1;

        my %parsedVars; # this is the new hash, allocated
                        # each time a new section is allocated

        # parse the variables as before, storing in the hash

        # when done:
        $sections{$parsedName} = \%parsedVars;

    }
}
```